# How would you add fall back support for background color with alpha for legacy browsers?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the background color but I want to use the alpha channel. Is there a way I can support new browsers with transparency and ensure older browsers show the correct color when transparency is not an option?

For example, will the following be sufficient or will the second value cancel the first:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);       // older browsers
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); // newer browsers
```

**UPDATE:**
I do not care to support transparency on older browsers. I want to make sure that older browsers use show the correct background color and newer browsers, if they support it, show the alpha channel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a translucent PNG file as a background for older browsers. Something like the below:

[image]

What happens with this is, check out the snippet:

```css
.parent {position: relative; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 20px; border: 1px solid #999; display: inline-block;}
.child {position: absolute; width: 50px; left: 50px; top: 50px; height: 50px; background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Black_%2850%25_transparent%29.png") repeat;}

#one {background: #ff9;}
#two {background: #99f;}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="one">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent" id="two">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't know you could do that. I will look into if this solves my issue but I'm not sure I can change the markup only the css. But I worded the question incorrectly. I do not need to support transparency in older browsers. I only want to ensure if I use RGBA for newer browsers that older browsers will still display a color (even if it is not transparent).

Comment: They'll just ignore the rgba.

Comment: So I can set background-color twice and old browsers will ignore the rgba and new ones will pick it up?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Old browsers ignore the `rgba` color. But to hide the translucent PNG from newer browsers (or simply use a solid color), you typically use conditional comments or CSS browser hacks.